# Passport deserializeUser never called

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am integrating Passport in my NodeJs APP and the signup works, the login in itself works but when redirecting directly after logging in my Session.Passport is empty again and deserializeUser is never called. Maybe someone sees where I made a mistake or has a clue to what I did wrong.

First my settings for Passport isinde my app.js:

```
app.use(session({ cookie: { maxAge: 18000 }, 
                  secret: cryptoSecret,
                  resave: false, 
                  saveUninitialized: true,
                  secure: false,
                  store: new memoryStore({checkPeriod: 86400000}),
                }));


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

My Local Strategy etc:

```
    // =========================================================================
    // passport session setup ==================================================
    // =========================================================================
    // required for persistent login sessions
    // passport needs ability to serialize and unserialize users out of session

    // used to serialize the user for the session
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        console.log('Serialize User');
        console.log(user);
        console.log('---------------------------------------');
        console.log(user._id);
        console.log('---------------------------------------');
        done(null, user._id);
    });

    // used to deserialize the user
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        console.log('deserialize Important!');
        
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            console.log(err);
            done(err, user);
        });
    });
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form        
        // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
        // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
        User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
            // if there are any errors, return the error before anything else
            if (err)
                return done(err);

            // if no user is found, return the message
            if (!user)
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash

            // if the user is found but the password is wrong
            if (!user.validPassword(password))
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata

            // all is well, return successful user
            return done(null, user);
        });

    }));
};
```

And here is my Login-route:

```
router.post('/', cors(), passport.authenticate('local-login',  { failureRedirect : '/', failureFlash : true}), (req, res) => {    
    console.log('Login route!  Authenticated?:', req.isAuthenticated(), ' Session:' , req.session);
    req.logIn(req.session.passport.user, err => {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      res.redirect('/group');
    });
       
});
```

I get the same behaviour when using successRedirect instead of the res.redirect :/

Session directly after authenticating:

[image: Session1]

And my Session when redirecting:

[image: Session2]

I tracked it down to my deserializeUser-function not beeing called and read so many SO entrys and other sites with no change. Getting a bit frustrated atm.
First of all thank you all for reading and helping. I appreciate every bit of information that might help me with this. I hope you all have a nice day :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that session is not working, since after redirection the `passport` entry in your session is empty, it's normal that passport will not call `deserializeUser`.

Your comment seems to confirm the problem is in session system.

A minimal working session system could be:

```
const session = require("client-sessions");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({ cookie: { ephemeral: true }, cookieName: "session", secret: "keyboardcat" }));
```

If neither this makes work your session system, I suggest you to check if something is making cookies not working in your setup.

Comment: any suggestion how to go about it? I changed my Session set-up to look like this now: 
``` 
    app.use(session({
        name : 'app.sid',
        cookie: {maxAge: 24*60*60*1000},
        secret: cryptoSecret,
        resave: true,
        store: new memoryStore({checkPeriod: 86400000}),
        saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

Comment: Before spend time on a problem, check it, @Soulrox . I said "it seems that the problem is that session is not working". Please check it by saving a custom data in the session and checking if it works or not; than we can say for sure if the problem is session system or in auth system

Comment: I added a token to my session and changed its value before redirecting and the change doesn't persist either

Comment: It seems my suspect was confirmed @Soulrox , please check my updated answer

Comment: Well I think I found the problem. When I changed express-session to client-session it suddenly worked, at least the deserializeUser function is now called. The new site still doesn't really load, on manual going to the site it works though. (Strange behaviour this redirecting stuff^^)

Comment: Good and bad news @Soulrox . It's strange it doesn't work after the redirect: it's the normal implementation and I can't see any valid reason why it shouldn't work. If you want to share some more code... Anyway the fact now (for other cases) it works is a good news. More than this, why are you using `cors` ? It's always a bad idea to use it where it is not strictly required.

Comment: I had problems with cors priviously and just didn't remove it until now. I am going to try the sucessRedirect again when I am back at work, maybe this works now. At least the session works now, which was my biggest problem. If the sucessRedirect works everything is good^^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217812/discussion-between-soulrox-and-daniele-ricci).

Comment: Sorry @Soulrox but I'm too busy to chat... I can try anyway...

Answer (score 0):

When you use `passport.authenticate()` as a route middleware you don't need `req.logIn()` because
this middleware invokes `req.login()` automatically to establish a login session.

See [`req.login()`](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/login/) in the passport docs.

`console.log('Login route!  Authenticated?:', req.isAuthenticated(), ' Session:' , req.session);`
shows the user is already authenticated.

I think the issue is that `req.logIn()` doesn't succeed and it overwrites the session, so you get different
`_expries` time in `/login` and `/group`. Also try increasing the `maxAge`, you set it to 18 seconds

Try this

```
router.post('/login', cors(), passport.authenticate('local-login', { 
    failureRedirect: '/', failureFlash: true 
}), (req, res) => {
    // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
    console.log('Login route!  Authenticated?:', req.isAuthenticated(), ' Session:', req.session);
    res.redirect('/group');
})
```

Comment: No offense, but you should definetly read other answers and comments before posting.

Comment: "All roads lead to Rome" @Soulrox, I am glad your issue is solved, but on SO you can always add an answer even if there is already an accepted answer.

Comment: Thats true, it just stroke me as illogical to post an answer to a question where the last comment, which was posted 3h before your answer, says that a solution was found and what it was^^ I still appreciate you effort :)